# Ms Access breaking DateDiff iif function

Tags: ms-access, syntax, ms-office, datediff, iif

I have a calculated column to check if "Last Payment" is less than 90 days from "withdrawaldate". Expression:

```
IIf(DateDiff('d',[Last Payment],[withdrawaldate])<=90,'1')
```

If I edit this in sql view it works perfectly. However if i edit this using query builder it breaks and says "Invalid syntax" highlighting '1' as the invalid section.

"Last Payment" is also a calculated field if that makes any difference?

What am I missing??

Please help

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

SQL view as Follows:

`SELECT
    Book.Cause_Date, 
    Book.Is_Archived, 
    Book.Status, Book.Handover_Status, 
    Max(Payments.[Capture Date]) AS [Last Payment], 
    Withdrawaltest.ACCOUNTNO, 
    Withdrawaltest.WITHDRAWALDATE, 
    Withdrawaltest.WITHDRAWALREASON, 
    IIf(Abs(DateDiff('d',[Last Payment],    [WITHDRAWALDATE])<=90)='1',"Yes","No") AS [Paid in 90Days], 
    IIf((Abs(DateDiff('m',[Cause_Date],[WITHDRAWALDATE])<=14)='1' And   [Handover_Status]='3') Or (Abs(DateDiff('m',[Cause_Date],   [WITHDRAWALDATE])<=9)='1' And [Handover_Status]='1'),'No','Yes') AS     [Out Of Term], 
    IIf([Paid in 90Days]="Yes" Or [Out Of   Term]="No","KEEP","DontBother") AS [Keep?]
FROM
    Payments RIGHT JOIN (Book INNER JOIN Withdrawaltest ON  Book.Case_Reference = Withdrawaltest.ACCOUNTNO) ON Payments.[Case   Reference] = Withdrawaltest.ACCOUNTNO
GROUP BY
    Book.Cause_Date, Book.Is_Archived, 
    Book.Status, Book.Handover_Status, Withdrawaltest.ACCOUNTNO, 
    Withdrawaltest.WITHDRAWALDATE, Withdrawaltest.WITHDRAWALREASON, 
    IIf((Abs(DateDiff('m',[Cause_Date],[WITHDRAWALDATE])<=14)='1' And   [Handover_Status]='3') Or (Abs(DateDiff('m',[Cause_Date],
[WITHDRAWALDATE])<=9)='1' And [Handover_Status]='1'),'No','Yes')
ORDER BY
    Max(Payments.[Capture Date]) DESC;`

Comment: confusing us - You should show your SQL View - and why is Query Builder any different - are you talking about Design View? - maybe show a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

First, your expression is missing the "False" part of the `IIf`:

```
IIf(DateDiff('d',[Last Payment],[withdrawaldate])<=90, '1', <FALSE-PART>)
```

Second, if you use German Access, then you must use `;` instead of `,` for functions in Query design view.

```
IIf(DateDiff('d';[Last Payment];[withdrawaldate])<=90; '1'; <FALSE-PART>)
```

But in SQL view (that's "international") it is `,`.

Comment: Thank you Andre, Il take a look at that

In the meantime I've ammended it to this:

`IIf(Abs(DateDiff('d',[Last Payment],[WITHDRAWALDATE])<=90)='1',"Yes","No")`

And it seems to work quite nicely